# Retrieve the districts from database using PostgreSQL

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I want to retrieve districts and state from the database, and also to populate second dropdown list based on first dropdown list. In my code below the values are inserted directly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Program Files\BitNami WAPPStack\apache2\htdocs \Prj\Online\jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var options = $('#test2 option');
        $('#test1').on('change', function(e) {
            $('#test2').append(options);
            if ($(this).val() != 'Select') {
                $('#test2 option[value!=' + $(this).val() + ']').remove();
            } else {
                $('#test2').val('Select');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="fid1.html">
        <select name="test1" id="test1">
            <option value="Select">Select</option>
            <option value="a">TamilNadu</option>
            <option value="b">Kerala</option>
            <option value="c">Andhra</option>
        </select>
        <select id="test2" name="test2">
            <option value="Select">Select</option>
            <option value="a">Chennai</option>
            <option value="a">Trichy</option>
            <option value="a">Madurai</option>
            <option value="b">Trivandram</option>
            <option value="b">Cochin</option>
            <option value="b">Azhapuzha</option>
            <option value="c">Hyderabad</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for that purpose you should use Ajax call on your first drop box .
Ajax is a server side tools to fetch data from database.

1. Create a ajax function, for example get_country()

`$(function() {
            $('#test1').change( function() {
                var val = $(this).val();`

```
                $.ajax({
                   url: 'findState.php',
                   dataType: 'html',
                   data: { country : val },
                   success: function(data) {
                       $('#state').html( data );
                   }
                });
            }
            else {
               $('#state').val('').hide();
               $('#othstate').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

now do your database query on findstate.php and use `state div` to show particuler state list.